# There has to be a better way to substr

Tags: c

Hi guys I'm currently using the code below and I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do it. What the code does is look if there's the delimiter (~~~~), puts everything before ~~~~ in cmd and everything after ~~~~ in param. If anyone could let me know how I should be doing this then it would be very appreciated! I'm not used to low-level languages so strings and pointers are still confusing to me!

Thanks!

```
char buffer[1024], *tempCharPointer, cmd[100], param[1024];

if(strstr(buffer, "~~~~"))
{
   strcpy(cmd, buffer);
   tempCharPointer = strstr(buffer, "~~~~");
   index = (tempCharPointer-buffer) + 4;
   strcpy(param, &tempCharPointer[4]);
   memmove(&cmd[index-4], "", (index-4));
}
```

Comment: do you need unmodified original string?

Comment: Unlikely the professor said yes or no to that one.  ;-)

Comment: This isn't for a professor, I learned how to code on my own for the past 10 years, I'm just used to higher-level languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code as follows:

```
char cmd[1024], *tempCharPointer, *param = "";
// Fill in cmd from somewhere...
...
char *delim = strstr(cmd, "~~~~");
if(delim)
{
    param = delim+4;
    *delim = '\0';
}
```

Comment: I was too lazy to write the code for it :P Gotta let people do some of the work at least

Comment: @user2204015 Four minutes between posting and getting an answer is *not* "crazy fast" on Stack Overflow: some questions get answered within a minute :)

Comment: I always knew about stackoverflow but I never bothered using it I usually just google a lot and find something that works, I'm obviously going to use it more now haha

Comment: @user2204015 You're welcome. You may want to accept an answer (and then go back to the other questions that you asked, and see if there's something that you could accept there). This would give you a new badge and a couple of rep points, and let others know that you are no longer actively looking for an improved answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code and insert `\0` before the delimiter (modify the first character of the delimiter and make it `\0`) and have command be a pointer to the beginning of the string and param a pointer to the first character after the delimiter. Saves you memory and all these moves and such.

Comment: @75inchpianist Yeah your comment popped up when I hit submit answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
char buffer[1024], *tempCharPointer, cmd[100], param[1024];

tempCharPointer = strstr(buffer, "~~~~");

if (tempCharPointer){
   *tempCharPointer = '\0';
   tempCharPointer +=4;

    //now buffer points to the first half, and tempCharPointer points to second half
    //do with them what you will
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `strtok` function in the C library (extract tokens from strings) can be useful here.

A small example follows. `man strtok` for more info. Note that strtok_r (used below) is used for reentrant support.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(const int argc, const char const** argv)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    sprintf(buffer, "~~~~foo~~~~bar~~~~baz");

    char* saveptr = NULL;
    char* token = strtok_r(buffer, "~~~~", &saveptr);
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        printf("TOKEN: %s\n", token);
        token = strtok_r(NULL, "~~~~", &saveptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: strtok() has some nasty (perhaps unexpected) results for those not familiar with it.  Be very careful, and read the man page (or standard text) on it in detail.

Comment: `strtok_r(buffer, "~~~~", &saveptr)` will split `"one~~two~~~~three"` into `{"one", "two", "three"}`, while the OP wants `{"one~~two", "three"}` This is because `delims` contains a sequence of characters each one of which can he a delimiter by itself.